# How to write an autocomplete inside a body selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am tried writing the following script:-

```
$('body').on("autocomplete", "#ServerTag", autocomplete () {

        minLength: 1, delay: 1000,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Content("~/Server/AutoComplete")",
                    dataType: "json",

                    data: {
                        term: request.term,
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },

            });
```

but it seems that i can not write the autocomplete after a body.on ? i want to write it this way to allow autocomplete to run on new content .
can anyone advice ?

Comment: this might get u Started http://jsfiddle.net/6mtYe/

Comment: so you mean i need to use     "$("#ServerTag").live("focus.autocomplete", null, function () { " instead of "$('body').on("autocomplete", "#ServerTag", autocomplete () {"

Comment: yes u can try using live

Comment: Awesome!! , please mark as answer if u feel it is right , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the live event with focus.autocomplete

something like

```
$("#ServerTag").live("focus.autocomplete", null, function () {});
```

instead of

```
$('body').on("autocomplete", "#ServerTag", autocomplete () {});
```